# Обновление свойств контроллера из SSE

Tags: angularjs

Есть вывод списка из контроллера:

```
<div ng-controller="Queuo">
    <div class="edit ui-list-view-bordered" ui-list-view="edit in edits" style="font-size:14px;">
        <div ng-click="select(edit)">{{ edit.name }}</div>
     </div>
</div>
```

Есть контроллер:

```
angular.module("swv", ["ui-listView"]).controller("Queuo", function ($scope) {

    $scope.edits = [
    {
        "name": "ruwiki",
        "id": "12345"
    },
    {
        "name": "enwiki",
        "id": "23457"
    }
    ];

    var source = new EventSource("https://stream.wikimedia.org/v2/stream/recentchange");
    source.onmessage = function(event) {
        var stuff = JSON.parse(event.data);
        var new_el = { "name": stuff.wiki, "id": stuff.id };
        $scope.edits.splice( 0, 0, new_el);
    }
});
```

Мне нужно, чтобы в реалтайме из ServerSentEvent данные добавлялись в контроллер и выводились в моём списке. Однако с кодом SSE не выводятся даже первые два добавляемых изначально элемента. Если его убрать, выводятся. Что я сделал не так?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Дело в том, что вы меняете значение `$scope.edits` за пределами области видимости ангуляра.

Для того, что бы выполнить функцию в контексте ангуляра, используйте `$scope.$apply`.

Пример.

```js
angular.module("swv", []).controller("Queuo", function($scope) {

  $scope.edits = [{
      "name": "ruwik3i",
      "id": "12345"
    },
    {
      "name": "enwiki",
      "id": "23457"
    }
  ];

  var source = new EventSource("https://stream.wikimedia.org/v2/stream/recentchange");
  source.onmessage = function(event) {
    var stuff = JSON.parse(event.data);
    var new_el = {
      "name": stuff.wiki,
      "id": stuff.id
    };
    $scope.$apply(function() {
      $scope.edits.unshift(new_el);
    });
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="swv">
  <div ng-controller="Queuo">
    <div class="edit ui-list-view-bordered" ng-repeat="edit in edits" style="font-size:14px;">
      <div ng-click="select(edit)">{{ edit.name }}</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```